# Blank screen while packaging electron app on W10

Tags: electron

I build an app with electron on Windows 10 (On mac was working very well).

So when I test the app on W10: cmd "electron ." it's working fine with all the content.
And when i build with "npx electron-packager ." it create the folder with the exe but when I open the exe I have a white blank screen (I have the menu bar but the content of the windows is white/empty)

Many thank for helping